# JavaScript Harmony - what it is?

Tags: javascript

1. What will Harmony mean for me as a programmer?
2. I have various JavaScript programs... will I have to re-write these?
3. How should I get ready for it? Can I already begin programming against Harmony?
4. When will it be released?

Comment: My crystal ball is also blue-screening so I unfortunately cannot help you. (Read: this is not the right kind of question(s) for Stack Overflow.)

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato Home work? Well, there is not school now and why would you think so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What will Harmony mean for me as a programmer?

More options

> I have various JavaScript programs... will I have to re-write these?

No

> How should I get ready for it?

At the moment, there really isn't much you can do beyond the usual "becoming a better programmer in general".

> Can I already begin programming against Harmony?

Not practically. Chrome, at least, [has some features implemented](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2011/12/29/00.00.29/) (but not in such a way that you can use them on the WWW).

> When will it be released?

Possibly by [the end of 2013](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/02/future-of-javascript-take-peek-today.html), but it will be longer before there is widespread support in the browsers on people's computers.

Comment: ...look forward to block scoping!