# What is harmony and what are harmony exports?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-harmony

What is this harmony exports? In fact, what is harmony?

**Background**

When I bundle stuff using Webpack and I look at the distribution source, it contains this one block always.

```
// define getter function for harmony exports
__webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
    if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
        Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
    }
};
```

I Googled and found [this page](https://github.com/filipesilva/webpack-harmony-exports) but I understand nothing on it. As of today, this page reads like so:

[image]

I googled more and [found a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601443/javascript-harmony-what-it-is) asking what harmony is, but the asker never asked it in so many words and the only answer does not tell you what it is.

**Question**

So, what on God's own green earth is harmony? And then what are harmony exports?

Reading the Stack Overflow tag description for 'ecmascript-harmony', I suspect it refers to ES6 module exports but I also think it isn't that, because immediately afterwards, the Webpack source distribution file has an `if` construct checking for whether the `entry` file it is processing exposes an ES 6 Module using the `export` statement.

```
// define __esModule on exports
__webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
    if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
        Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
    }
    Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
};
```

So, it probably means something other than ES 6 modules exports? I suspect it is the *Common JS* style export as implemented in Node?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> So, what on God's own green earth is harmony?

[After ES4 was abandoned, plans were scaled back in a new project which had the code name Harmony.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_version_history#4th_Edition_(abandoned))

This eventually evolved into ES6.

> And then what are harmony exports?

The [exports system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#exporting_module_features) that ES6 describes the final (?) version of.